# Trying to identify pieces from an image

Tags: part-identification

I'm trying to recreate this MOC but I'm having trouble identifying some parts just from the image.

1.) Can you tell me what part the 3 rear legs on each side are?

2.) What are the brown and beige pieces that connect at the end of its claws? The brown one looks like it has a clip on the bottom and the beige piece looks like it has a bar handle but I'm not too sure.

I figured out all other pieces but I'm not 100% sure about what is used for the butt so I would be happy to get some ideas, but it's not necessary.[image]

Comment: The thorax is built using [Reddish Brown Slope, Curved 2 x 2 x 2/3 with 2 Studs and Curved Sides](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=47457&colorID=88&in=A) pieces.

Comment: Rock and Stone brother!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The back legs consist of the following pieces:

- [53451 Barb / Claw / Horn / Tooth - Small](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=53451&ccName=6270106#T=C&C=1)
- [98313 Arm Mechanical, Exo-Force / Bionicle, Thick Support](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=107525&idColor=11&ccName=6006739#T=C&C=11)
- [92692 Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Angled Bar Handles on Side](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=92692#T=C)

[image: Piece 53451]
[image: Piece 98313]
[image: Piece 92692]

As for the front claw connectors, I'm not 100% sure, but it could be [25893 Plate, Round 1 x 1 with Bar Handle on Short Stem](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=25893&idColor=12#T=S&C=11&O=%7B%22color%22:%2211%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D). I don't know if that piece is available in that color, though.

[image: Piece 25893]

Comment: ah nice. i found the calw pretty quick but couldnt find the arm. thanks

Comment: @Choty Please see the following article: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: i can work with that. thanks :)